# Call html javascript function from vb window form in vb.net

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I have an html file with a javascript function called as `JsInHtml()`

I want to call `JsInHtml()` from a VB window form called `form1.vb` without using a web browser control.

Can anyone please explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the JavaScript function when an ASP.NET button control is clicked then please use the OnClientClick property of the Button control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx).

There is an example on the webpage I have provided showing how to call a JavaScript function called Navigate from ASP.NET.

If this does not help, then please post more details, explaining when the JavaScript function should be called and I will help further.